# Posting two input arrays via jquery at the same time

Tags: jquery, html, mysql

I am appending multiple input boxes and  successfully posting one input array to the mysql as here it is.

```
$('<p><input type="text"  class="name" name="task" ></p>').appendTo($('#add_here'));

function addmem(id, text, number) {
    $('input.name').each(function() {
        // var te=$('input.task').val();
        $.post(
            'sendchat2.php', 
            { option: 'add_mem', id: id , text: $(this).val() }, 
            function(data) {
                alert(data);
            });
        });
    }
```

But now I need to post two input arrays at the same time. One input is customer name and another is his mobile number. I tried the below, but its not working correctly. Please help or suggest any alternative approach.

```
$('<p><input type="text"  class="name" ><input type="text"  class="number" name="task" ></p>').appendTo($('#add_here'));

function addmem(id, text, number) {
    $('input.name').each(function() {
        $('input.number').each(function() {
            $.post(
                'sendchat2.php', 
                { option: 'add_mem', id: id, text: $(this).val(), number: $(this).val()}, 
                function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            );
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the markup will always fit the scheme `<name><number>`

```
function addmem(id, text, number) {
    $('input.name').each(function() {
        var input = $(this),
            name = input.val(),
            number = input.next().val();

        $.post(
            "sendchat2.php", 
            { "option": "add_mem", "id": id, "text": name, "number": number }, 
            function(data) {
               alert(data);
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: ,teted this,but its not working.number is returned as undefined index.

Comment: Please show us an example with the markup and your javascript on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) or [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com) so we can experiment with it

Answer (score 2):

You should use the $.ajax{}) function instead of $.post.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: array1.serialize() + array2.serialize(), //(if this info is coming from a form, just do $(form identifier).serialize(); and it will send all form elements).
  url: <destination url>
  success: function (data){
          <what you want to do when the request is successful here>
         }
})
```

Doing it this way, you only make 1 ajax call with all of your data, as opposed to an ajax call on each iteration through your loop. It should be much more efficient.

I think this function is also easier to use with multiple data sources, but I am sure you could probably come up with a way to do this with $.post also (perhaps serializing both arrays, or combining the two arrays into one before passing to the server. If you can give me an idea of what your form looks like, I be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

the thing that stands out is this loop

```
$('input.name').each(function(){

    $('input.number').each(function(){

$.post('sendchat2.php', {option:'add_mem', id:id , text:$(this).val(),number:$(this).val()}, function(data) {
 alert(data);
});
    });

});
```

it looks like you are assigning the same value to the `text` and `number` post variables, since the `this` keyword will always refer to the `input.number` element in the inner `each` loop. try this:

```
$('input.name').each(function(){
  var nameval = $(this).val();

  $('input.number').each(function(){
    var numval = $(this).val();

    $.post('sendchat2.php', {option:'add_mem', id:id , text:nameval, number:numval}, function(data) {
     alert(data);
    });

  });
});
```